# Access dynamic file in .NET CORE 2

Tags: c#, file, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out a way to deploy .NET Core project containing files that are acting as data storage. I'm using .csv files. I will be modifying these files, both manually and programmatically. This project could potentially be deployed to Windows, Linux, and Mac, so I don't know where these files should be located. I've attempted to make them embedded resources and access them via scoping to the assembly, but any changes to these files don't seem to be represented when accessing this way.

How would I go about achieving what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The location to store data files like that varies between systems. For the most part, you're supposed to use environment variables to store data in a subfolder of the appdata folder on Windows or a subfolder of a user's home directory on Linux. (And probably OS X too, though I don't know that one)

Alternatively, you can write a program that is "portable" or doesn't need to be installed to run, and you can store your data files in the same folder your application is run from.